# Reasons why tests on teamcity can be ignored

Tags: selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, teamcity

There are jobs on team city and sometimes some test in them randomly ignored

I have this in logs

```
 [TestSuite] com.aero.mai.ui.app.setup.settingsTest.closeBrowser

    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
```

Comment: Any suggestions why this happening? There are no dependencies in test on other tests

Comment: It seems your browser was already closed or in ur code u might have lost the browser instance or something. It would be good if u debug ur test case and check that before a call to `closeBrowser` is ur driver alive? i.e. on entering this method ur driver instance persists.